# Wait for async completion before returning

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, durandal, amd

This code returns a config object, and eventually populates it with knockout observables.

```
define("config", [], function () {
  var config = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: "api/Config",
    success: function (result) {
      for (pname in result)
        config[pname] = ko.observable(result[pname]);
    },
  });
  return config;
});
```

It works in terms of populating the config object with settings, but it doesn't finish until after one of my views has applied bindings, and this causes problems at runtime.

How would you set this up to wait on the result of the ajax query before returning the config object? My first thought was using a promise object, but I can't see how to apply it.

I'm not looking for a workaround, I already have one:

```
define("config", [], function () {
  var config = {
    IsReady: ko.observable()
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: "api/Config",
    success: function (result) {
      jquery.extend(config, result);
      config.IsReady(true);
    },
  });
  return config;
});
```

With this setup I bind like this

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: config.IsReady() ? config.Logo : '' }" />
```

But I don't want to pollute my views with that rubbish, so I want to know how to wait on an async operation before returning from a factory method.

Trying to apply advice received so far, I turned things inside out. Because `result` is now in scope and ready to use when define is called, I simply pass it directly to define.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/Config",
    success: function (result) {
      define("config", [], result);
    }
});

//the following code should not execute until config has been defined.

define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator'], 
       function (system, app, viewLocator) {
  //>>excludeStart("build", true);
  system.debug(true);
  //>>excludeEnd("build");

  app.title = 'Jumbo File Transfer';

  app.configurePlugins({
    router: true,
    dialog: true,
    widget: true
  });

  app.start().then(function () {
    //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
    //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
    viewLocator.useConvention();

    //Show the app by setting the root view model for our app with a transition.
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
  });
});
```

This runs but leaves the question of how to make the rest of the application wait till this has happened. So I put the rest of main.js inside the success function, like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/Config",
  success: function (result) {
    define("config", [], result);
    define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator'], 
           function (system, app, viewLocator) {
      //>>excludeStart("build", true);
      system.debug(true);
      //>>excludeEnd("build");

      app.title = 'Jumbo File Transfer';

      app.configurePlugins({
        router: true,
        dialog: true,
        widget: true
      });

      app.start().then(function () {
        //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
        //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
        viewLocator.useConvention();

        //Show the app by setting the root view model for our app with a transition.
        app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
      });
    });
  }
});
```

This actually *does* execute in the right order - I stepped through it. But the app fails to start. If I had to guess why, I would say define wants `this` to be the global context.

Nathan's answer below doesn't stop Durandal from starting properly but the behaviour of the config define isn't quite right. I need config defined as an object full of settings properties, not an object with a factory method. But we're nearly there. It just needs to look like this:

```
define('configFactory', ['plugins/http'], function (http) {
  "use strict";
  var getConfig = function () { 
    return http.get("api/Config").then(function (data) { return data; });
  };
  return { getConfig: getConfig };
});
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'configFactory'], 
       function (system, app, viewLocator, configFactory) {

  //>>excludeStart("build", true);
  system.debug(true);
  //>>excludeEnd("build");

  app.title = 'Jumbo File Transfer';

  app.configurePlugins({
    router: true,
    dialog: true,
    widget: true
  });

  configFactory.getConfig().then(function (config) {
    define('config', [], config);
    app.start();
  }).then(function () {
    //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
    //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
    viewLocator.useConvention();

    //Show the app by setting the root view model for our app with a transition.
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
  });
});
```

---

### In hindsight

You can make ajax block by setting the async option to false, like this.

```
var foo;

$.ajax({ 
  url:"whatever", 
  async: false
}).done(function(result){ 
  foo = result;
});

//code that needs result
```

However, introducing a bottleneck is seldom a good idea.

Here's the fundamental problem: the below will fail because config doesn't have a property `foo` until after the first rendering pass.

```
<span data-bind="text:config.foo"><span>
```

We could synchronously load config in main, but a better answer is to defer binding until `foo` is available.

```
<!-- ko if: config.foo -->
<span data-bind="text:config.foo"><span>
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

You don't need to be explicit like this in the template for a foreach binding, since the template is rendered for each instance. You need only pre-declare the `observableArray`.

Comment: Shouldn't you not construct or render the view until the ajax response is received?  In Backbone.js, the view is not constructed until the collection is fetched by ajax. I'd imagine the same goes for knockout.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [http plugin](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#module/http/method/get) in durandal to handle this.

```
define(['plugins/http', 'services/logger'], function (http, logger) {
    "use strict";
    var getConfig = function () {
        return http.get("api/Config").then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    };
    return {
        getConfig: getConfig
    };
});
```

It should then be a matter of doing

```
define(['durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/viewLocator', 'config'], 
       function (system, app, viewLocator, config) {
  //>>excludeStart("build", true);
  system.debug(true);
  //>>excludeEnd("build");

  app.title = 'Jumbo File Transfer';

  app.configurePlugins({
    router: true,
    dialog: true,
    widget: true,
    http: true
  });

  config.getConfig().then(app.start()).then(function () {
    //Replace 'viewmodels' in the moduleId with 'views' to locate the view.
    //Look for partial views in a 'views' folder in the root.
    viewLocator.useConvention();

    //Show the app by setting the root view model for our app with a transition.
    app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
  });
});
```

**Edit**
I think you just need to add what you had in your `done` function of the ajax call to get what you need.

```
define('configFactory', ['plugins/http'], function (http) {
  "use strict";
  var getConfig = function () { 
    return http.get("api/Config").then(function (data) { 
        var config = {};

        for (pname in data){
             config[pname] = ko.observable(data[pname]);
        }

        return config; 
    });
  };
  return { getConfig: getConfig };
});
```

Comment: This almost works. See my question edits. Very interested in your input.

Comment: Which bit doesn't work?  and are you talking about the edits from an hour ago?

Comment: No, the latest ones. Got sidetracked, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This is a usecase for promises. I'm not sure about javascript's cross browser support for this, but it seems to be like in other async languages. 
[Full raw javascript example on this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/?redirect_from_locale=de)

If you use jquery, it gets even easier:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
}).done(function( data ) {
  if(console && console.log ) {
    console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
  }
});
```

[JQuery Docs about Ajax Promises](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: This is fine for scheduling additional behaviour when an aync action completes, but it doesn't block the *calling* context. I can put the rest of main.js in the done handler which does solve the specific problem but it doesn't teach me how to synchronise the asynchronous.

Comment: I can see from your edit now. Well, doubt you can get rid of that because even if you set config.Logo to a wrapper object containing that logic, its not defined before .done/success got executed.. Which leads me to the question: why is the view ahead of time ? That's what I'd change if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `config` like you are.  You simply can't.  The ajax call is asynchronous so it will return immediately and you will return an empty `config` object.  The only way to handle this with asynchronous ajax is to design for asynchronous code.  You can either use promises or you can call a function from your success handler and pass it the now finished `config` object.  Either way, you're going to get the finished `config` object in a callback function.

```
define("config", [], function () {
  var config = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: "api/Config",
    success: function (result) {
      for (pname in result) {
        config[pname] = ko.observable(result[pname]);
      }
      // call your function now and pass it the completed config object
      callMyFunction(config);
    }

  });
});
```

You may think this is a work-around, but it is how you code for asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler answer.
If you make your `config` observable, then you can update it later:

```
define("config", [], function () {
  var config = ko.observable({}); // 1. Make config observable
  $.ajax({
    url: "api/Config",
    success: function (result) {
      //for (pname in result) {
      //    config[pname] = ko.observable(result[pname]);
      //}
      config(result); // 2. Replace the existing config object
    },
  });
  return config;
});
```

So your html would be updated to:

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: config().Logo }" />
```

Comment: Do you know, I almost did that. Probably should have, it's as you say simpler. But sometimes it's about the journey.

Comment: This won't work as config() does not have a Logo property at binding time.