# How can I recognize that a JavaScript File is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the folowing problem:

My site is loading jQuery in the head section. It has the "async" flag so it's loading asynchronisly.
I have written some functions using jQuery und manipulating the content.

When I implement this functions at the end of the jQuery file, sometimes jQuery is loaded before the whole DOM of the website. That means my functions cannot find the special elements and don't do anything.
If I implement this funktions at the end of the HTML file, when the DOM is already loaded, it happens that the webpage is finished but jQuery not. Then I get the error that the jQuery reference is not defined.

Has anyone an idea how i can fix this dilemma? Loading JS asynchronisly and calling functions, when DOM and JS file has been loaded?

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: Don't load jQuery asynchronously?

Comment: Make your other `script` tag async as well? *"When I implement this functions at the end of the jQuery file, sometimes jQuery is loaded before the whole DOM of the website."* I'm not even going to ask why you add your code to the jQuery file. However, I hope you know about the `ready` handler, which executes code as soon as the DOM is loaded: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Isn't it all about jQuery $(document).ready()?

Comment: @fallenPhantasm - That is not what [`.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is for, since `$` won't even be usable if jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: If you *are* going to load asynchronously, use one of the "AMD" loaders; Require.js is pretty popular, but there are others - in short, this "problem" is already solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117935/how-do-amd-loaders-work-under-the-hood , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951407/wait-for-async-completion-before-returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't that difficult and doesn't require additional libraries or polling like the other answers suggest.

Script tags, including ones marked `async`, support an `onload()` function to call when they are loaded, and jQuery has the $(document).ready() method for when the DOM is loaded. You need to wait for both. So:

```
<script async src='jquery.js' onload='jqueryloaded()'></script>
<script>
    function jqueryloaded() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // all your code
        });
    }
</script>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fJLGJ/)

Comment: Thank you very much for this great hint! I implemented it the same way you said, but I get pthe error, that 'jqueryloaded' not defined is. Is it possible that loading jQuery can be faster then loading the whole HTML file and than it tries to call this function? Or do you have any other suggest?

Comment: Hmm... it might be possible if jquery is already cached, although I would still expect it to parse the page before running. The `async` functionality isn't consistent across browsers. But to get that error, I would double check your code for typos.

Comment: I added the function this way: 'function jqueryloaded() { my code }'. This is the code where jQuery is implemented: '<script async type="text/javascript" src="/templates/jquery.js" onload="jqueryloaded()"></script>'. I have seen that safari manipulates the async and looking at the html source code I get 'async=""'.

Comment: I solvd the problem using the solution of bhamlin. But I changed the oder. First Indeclare the function and then I use the onload event. That works very good and I don't have any problems. ThanksM

Answer (score 0):

use [require.js](http://requirejs.org).

Alternatively you can write something like this, which is not best practice:

```
var checkforjquery = setInterval(function() {
  if (window.jQuery) {
    clearInterval(checkforjquery);
    // all your jquery functions
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Uhhh.  You can't use `$(window).load()` or `$(document).ready()` when jQuery isn't loaded yet.

Comment: thats why i added the interval function

Comment: Your answer reads that you can do either the first thing OR the second thing.  If you intended something different, then please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [depend.js](https://gist.github.com/m93a/84d856efcccd4bfde2b6) library. Include (synchronously) the depend.js file in your `head` element, wrap the jquery code in

```
Library(
 "jquery",
 function(){
  //The jQuery itself goes here
});
```

and wrap every script that needs jQuery by this:

```
Script(
 "any-name",
 ["jquery"],
 function(){
  //The script body
});
```

You can use it even for your libraries. If a library depends on another library, just use `Library("mylib",["dependency1","dependency2"],f);`, where `f` is the library body.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Put all the javascript at the end of your page, jQuery first. Something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="script.js"></script> <!-- your code -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should put that inside the body, still :)

Comment: I think the OP's question is how to solve the problem when jQuery IS loaded asynchronously, not how to make jQuery NOT be loaded asynchronously.

Comment: Is this still valid HTML? I don't really think so.

Comment: Cheers Alex, you're right about that. I fixed it above.